# Forces acting along length of rope plucked up at one end

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, string

[image]

Consider an inextensible rope with forces $ F_1, F_2... F_n$ acting along it's length, and, $ F_o$ and $ F'$ acting on it's left and right end respectively. Now, Does the equality that the tension at one end is equal to sum of forces along the rope ?  [ the ropes shape does not vary w.r.t time ]

If so , how would I prove this equality? How would the force $ F'$ relate come into play?

Secondly, suppose this rope was extensible, how would the answer change?

---

**My attempts:**

I intuitively think that this result is true, but I"m not quite sure how to proof it and also a bit worried about the $ F'$ force at one end. And, I know that if the rope was extensible then it would bend at places but how that change the force balance equations?

What I don't get is what equation I should use to set up the solution. I thought of doing newton's second law which gives:

$$ F' + \sum F_i = 0$$

Because of equilibrium, and,

$$ F' = - \sum F_i$$

And since, $$ T= -F'$$

$$ T = \sum F_i$$

The part I'm confused about is, how do I justify $ T= -F'$ ? I think it should be by the second law but I'm slightly worried about where $ F_{o}^{'}$ comes in
is it wrong, Why/Why not?

Comment: Try IE irodov problem number 93 which is very similar of mechanics https://www.pdfdrive.com/irodov-problems-in-general-physics-e24882553.html

Comment: "A fixed pulley carries a weightless thread with masses m1
and m2 at its ends. There is friction between the thread and the pulley. ..." this one?

Comment: Yes now here instead of friction you have other forces

Comment: For me the question is not really clear. Of cause the two forces at both  ends have to be the sum of all the forces  Fi , but since you have two ends it depends of the direction of the forces at the end,

Comment: Ok, so how does direction come into play? and how do you prove that it must be same?